# Add date and timestamp on existing video

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-editing, mencoder, melt

I've searched the web thin trying to find some clever way of adding a dynamic date and timestamp on my videos.
All I can find are ways to add the current time - not the time of the video.

The Melt Framework almost offers a way to do it. It lets me add `dynamictext #timecode#` which adds the time starting from 00:00:00:00. If only I could add an offset to this, it would be solved.
It also lets me add `dynamictext #localfiledate#` but this is a static value that doesn't change as the minutes go by, meaning a 10 minute long video will say that all 10 minutes were recorded at the same minute.

As a tedious temporarily (I hope) solution, I'm converting my videos to images, and then scripting my way out of adding a date and timestamp to each image before reassembling to a video again. This works, but takes forever.

I know I can do this if I use Windows and editors like Sony Vegas or Adobe Premiere. I do not use Windows and do not have these editors. Surely there must be a way to do it using a command-line tool in Linux?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38747518/5726027

Comment: Thanks. Did not find that one in my searches. However, trying the command in the accepted answer, I'm just getting "Invalid format 'gmtime'"

Comment: Works here. Your ffmpeg build looks to be older than 2013. Or it could be an issue of escaping? The command works as-is on Win7.

Comment: ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Show the full console output

Comment: Alright. Got it working with v3.3, although sadly not quite there. I need to be able to format the date. Basically just show the date differently, and leave out seconds. There's something in the docs about strftime, but various different ways of writing it isn't getting me anywhere.

Comment: On Win7, this works for me: `text='Time\: %{pts\:gmtime\:1456007118\:%Y-%m-%d %H\\\:%M}'`

Comment: My problem is the escaping of the colon. I tried it like you've written there, but get this error back: Unterminated %{} near '{pts:localtime:1492436469:%d/%m %Y %H\'
If I don't use a colon, everything works fine.

Comment: Solved using %R instead of %H:%M :-)
Thanks a lot for your help Mulvya.
Something that worries me a bit though, is that the docs says the strftime thingy is deprecated. Do you know if this formatting option suddenly disappears in a future version?

Comment: Weird. %R doesn't work here. `strftime` expansion mode is deprecated. Not the use of strftime formatting with the `pts` function.